# Using Observe or other reactive function to output single dataframe cell in Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I'm stuck on the final, and most critical step in building out my first pretty basic web-app using Shiny, and I'm struggling with what I think should be a pretty basic task. The idea is for the app to observe two inputs and then output a single value from a dataframe based on both of them.

Example Code to make it very clear.

```
Server
    DF X Y Z
    1  A B C
    2  C D E
    3  F G H

UI
    InputA: Row - 2
    InputB: Column - Z

    Output: E
```

At the moment I've run into a total wall with this because I'm not getting an error. The App starts without a problem, and every other widget on this tab and others are working. At the moment, the text boxes just aren't doing anything. One can type values into the first two, but then nothing outputs and no error message is provided. It's frustrating because it feels at though I'm missing something very obvious.

Here is the actual code
Server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
#Download Data and create data table.
  rlwin <- read.csv("rlwinClean.csv")
...
observe({
    Lead <- as.character(input$Lead)
    CalcTime <- as.character(input$CalcTime)
    addtext <- paste(rlwin[rlwin$Time == CalcTime, Lead])
    updateTextInput(session,"winProbability", value=addtext)
    })
 }
...
```

The UI:

```
ui <- (navbarPage(theme=shinytheme("sandstone"), title=h3("Rocket League Win Probability"),
              #Tab1 ----
              tabPanel("Win Probability Model",
                       #The Plot
                       plotOutput("modPlot", height="800px"),
                       #Probabililty Calculator
                       h4("Win Probability Calculator"),
                       textInput(inputId="CalcTime", label="Enter Time on Clock Remaining in Game", placeholder="0:00 to 5:00"),
                       textInput(inputId="Lead", label="Enter Lead or Deficit", placeholder="-4 to 4"),
                       br(""),
                       textInput(inputId="winProbability",label="Win Probability",placeholder="50%"),
                       br("")
                       ),
```

...

Edit: Found an answer to this. It's probably a bit long winded

Server

```
...
observeEvent(input$runCalc,{
  time <- subset(react, GameClock == input$CalcTime)
  all <- subset(time, select = input$Lead)
  val <- paste(all)

updateTextInput(session, inputId = "probText", value = val)
})
....
```

UI was effectively unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your observer

```
my_observer <- observe({ .... })
```

Comment: So that didn't work, but I'd like to know what you expected it to do.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the issue could be due to the observer not persisting because it was not assigned. I've gone through your code more thoroughly and will post a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Note that I have renamed some of your inputs because it was difficult to keep track of where your inputs were supposed to be used.

The error was occurring because `addText` in your original code was empty (the logical conditions returned no records). You will see below how I printed output to the console to debug this.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- (navbarPage( title=h3("Rocket League Win Probability"),
                  #Tab1 ----
                  tabPanel("Win Probability Model",
                           textInput(inputId="column_name", label="Column name", placeholder="X, Y or Z"),
                           textInput(inputId="row_number", label="Row number", placeholder="1, 2 or 3"),
                           br(""),
                           textInput(inputId="winProbability",label="Win Probability",placeholder="50%"),
                           br("")
                  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Download Data and create data table.
  rlwin = data.frame(DF = c(1,2,3), X = c("A","B","C"), Y = c("B","D","G"), Z = c("C","E","H"))

  observe({
    col_name <- as.character(input$column_name)
    row_num <- input$row_number
    addtext <- paste(rlwin[row_num, names(rlwin) == col_name])
    # print("debug print out")
    # print(col_name)
    # print(row_num)
    # print(addtext)
    updateTextInput(session,"winProbability", value=addtext)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```